# How to trigger ONLY one element with twitter collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events

I am using twitter Bootstrap for expand-collapse effect and everythings is working but I have a problem when I click on some lement then all my divs with carousel class are expanding, does anyone knows how to solve this here is code example:

```
<div class="description collapse-group">
   <!-- This div with class mehr-pfeil I am using as trigger for collapse. If user clicks on it, the content of collapse element should show.-->
   <div class="mehr-pfeil" onclick=".collapse('toggle');">
      <!-- But if user clicks on heading <a> then it shall go directly to article -->
      <a href="/?id=2500,1111142">
      <span>04.07.2014</span>
      <span class="orange">&nbsp;</span><span>Some content <span>
      </a>
      <p class="collapse">Some content</p>
   </div>
   <p class="collapse">Nicht das Erfinden neuer Themen, sondern das Umsetzen bestehender bzw. der in den Klausuren definierten.</p>
</div>
```

ps. this is just one example of my content which should be triggered with collapse. Just imagine that you have more than one.

UPDATE: Also problem appears always when I click on collapse element. For instance, if one element was closed then another opens and vice versa.

So I wanted to know how to triger tis action only for one lement with js:

This on click event I am currently using:

```
onclick="$(\'#main-content\').find(\'.collapse\').collapse(\'toggle\');">'."\n";
```

Comment: Please add the sample in http://www.bootply.com/new#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) you should be able to correctly implement the expand-collapse effect.

It's a little unclear to me what you're trying to ask; your explanation isn't very clear to me and I'm a little unsure what your code is trying to accomplish. BUT from what I can tell, the source of your issue may be the lack of `id` and `href` attributes in your tags.

An example might be something like this:

```
<div class="panel">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsableDiv">Click me!</a>
  <div id="collapsableDiv" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <p>Nicht das Erfinden neuer...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't have the time to create a JSFiddle and check my work, but that's an example that should work for the fundamental basics of a bootstrap collapse. As long as you have `bootstrap.js` in your project you shouldn't need any custom JavaScript.

IMO using jQuery effects is cleaner and easier than Bootstrap; I am currently working on a project that was using Bootstrap collapse but the animation randomly stopped working, so I switched to using jQuery slide effects. Consider looking into that if bootstrap gives you too much trouble.